# .txt file on server wont open but same file changed to .css does?

Tags: url

Basically I get an error every time I try open or get this txt file via url. However when I change the extension to css it opens fine. I have tried re-uploading and it makes no difference.

Try for yourself:
http://seanbingley.comyr.com/DrKruseSite/articles.txt
http://seanbingley.comyr.com/DrKruseSite/articles.css

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I should probably state that I am not bothered about actually opening it in a browser. I need to read data from it for my website. However I cannot read the data if it keeps giving me 404.

Also when opening the txt file locally in a browser it works fine. It's just when I try to open the same file from the server it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a mime-type on IIS so it can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the hosting site (000webhost) does not allow txt files on free accounts.